# What are all the benefits of switching from Routify to SvelteKit 1.0

Tags: webpack, svelte, vite, sveltekit, routify

We are using [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) and [Routify](https://www.routify.dev/) for our SPA project. There's no need for SSR since our entire app requires authentication.

Now that [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) is officially stable ([see 1.0 announcement](https://svelte.dev/blog/announcing-sveltekit-1.0)), we are considering migrating to it.

If we do that, we're surely going to be using the [SPA mode](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#spa-mode) with the static adapter for the reasons mentioned above, so we're not going to take advantage of all of the benefits of the framework. Nevertheless, I can think of at least a few potential benefits of migrating, such as:

- Faster builds with [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) (we're currently using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/))
- Tree shaking
- Instant reloading with the [HMR API](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-hmr.html)
- Dynamically preloading components and data ([data-sveltekit-preload-data](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-preload-data))

What are the other potential benefits of switching from Routify to SvelteKit 1.0 that are not mentioned above and are there any drawbacks besides having to refactor the codebase?

Comment: IMO there would be close-to-zero benefit if you determine to stick to SPA. 3/4 pro pts you listed came directly from vite itself, not related to sveltekit. My two cents, just  switch from webpack to vite.

Comment: My experience with SvelteKit wasn't that great so far. The folder/filename based convention is quite complicated and a bit hard to grasp in short time. I strongly advice you start with a fresh toy project to get familiar with SvelteKit first. Otherwise those shinny new features will very likely end up being distractions that mislead you into bad decisions (it surely confused me couple times).

Comment: Tbh, I personally like the new filename convention as we naturally came to a pretty similar architecture in our Routify app. Nevertheless, you are making a good point about experimenting first. Thank you!

Comment: I’m largely ok with the filename base applied to routing. But this applies also to peripheral configuration ? Consider just one case: to say “I want this page to be prerendered”, I need a new file `+page.js` containing **just one line** `export let prerender = true`. Now imagine you have 10 `+page.js` like this littering your repo. That just hurts my eye a bit . I would prefer a configuration based escape hatch that involves just one file. I’d rather write more lines of code than creating bunch of files. That’s mainly my complaint.

Comment: Makes sense, I have the feeling that they will change this in the future to something like what you describe - a single config file.